# jQuery looping form fields and excluding radio buttons

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I have the following code that loops over elements in a form and creates a string I can pass as the URL

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// submit form
$('#getCodeRefine').submit(function(){
    var queryString = '/accommodation-results/params/'
    var fields = $( this ).serializeArray();
    jQuery.each( fields, function( i, field ) {
        if (field.value.length) {
            queryString += field.name + '/' + field.value + '/';
        }
     });
    $(this).attr('action', queryString);
    })
 });
```

Only problem is I'd like to exclude all radio buttons and i can't work out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude 'radio' buttons.

```
jQuery.each( fields, function( i, field ) {
   if(field.not(':radio')){
    if (field.value.length) {
        queryString += field.name + '/' + field.value + '/';
    }
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

see the detail about [`:radio`](https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) selector on [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) website

```
if($(this).is(:radio))
  // do something here    
}
```